# SQL update statement - Postgres and mysql compatibility

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

In mysql, one can execute the following statement:

```
UPDATE trx SET lock_id=somevalue WHERE lock_id is NULL order by stamp desc limit 1
```

I'm looking for a statement or statements run in transaction that would accomplish the same thing and would work in both MySQL 5.7 and PostgreSQL 9.4

It is important for this to be atomic, as this statement is in MySQL.

Comment: I don't think you're going to find cross-engine compatibility like this.  Instead, work up a one or the other dependent upon active engine from whatever code invokes this.

Comment: You can do `SELECT ... ORDER BY something LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE` and then issue an update on a locked row.